# Java, sum of rows and columns

Tags: java, matrix, sum

Hello I'm trying to calculate the sum of each row and column of a matrix and then print the sum of the smallest value. Right now I have run into a problem. The sum that I get "smallRows" sum I get is not the smallest row from the matrix. It is just the latest. How can I improve this?
Thanks in advance!

```
    {
        int rows = 4;
        int columns = 5;
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) 
            {
                matrix[i][j] = new Random().nextInt(9)  + 1;
            }   
        }
        printMatrix(matrix);
        int[] tempRows = new int[columns];
        int[] smallRows = new int[columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) 
            {
                tempRows[j] = matrix[i][j];
            }

            if(sum(smallRows) == 0)
            {
                smallRows = tempRows;
            }
            if (sum(tempRows) < sum(smallRows)) 
            {
                smallRows = tempRows;
            }
        }
    }
    public static int sum(int[] a)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            sum += a[i];    
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void printMatrix(int mat[][]) 
    { 
        for (int[] row : mat)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row)); 
    }
```

Comment: `smallRows = tempRows;` does not copy the array, it simple changes `smallRows` to refer to the same array as `tempRows`. Change to `smallRows = tempRows.clone();` --- However, since you're just supposed to print the sum value, not the row itself, why save the entire row, and not just the sum? Re-think what you're doing, considering the goal.

Comment: The end goal is to print the row/column with the smallest sum as well as the sum. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can find out the smallest value and its index and if it is from a row or column

```
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int indexOfSmallest = -1;
boolean isRow = true;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
    int value = sum(matrix[i]);
    if (value < smallest) {
        smallest = value;
        indexOfSmallest = i;
    } 
}
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) { 
    int columnSum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        columnSum += matrix[i][j];
    }
    if (columnSum < smallest) {
        smallest = columnSum;
        indexOfSmallest = i;
        isRow = false;
    }
}
```

After that you can print the row or column with the smallest value that `indexOfSmallest` and `isRow` points at.